# HTML data-attribute html element can't design directly

Tags: html, css, attributes, custom-data-attribute

I've write some HTML data-attribute code and added HTML tag inside. But I can't design them without adding any class name.

For example; this is my data-attribute;

```
<div data-box="<h1 class='my-div'> A Simple Heading</h1>"> This is a tag that have a data-attribute with html tag. </div>
```

If I want to design this , I can design it without any problem. Just declare the class in css stylesheet and design it. But if I want to Design the same h1 tag without any class, how can I do it ...?

```
<div data-box="<h1> A Simple Heading</h1>"> This is a tag that have a data-attribute with html tag. </div>
```

Look at the h1 tag, in this time How can I design it without adding any class name ?

Comment: Can you create a snippet where you illustrate your problem and edit your question, adding the snippet to it?

Answer (score -1):

You would need to select the attribute in your CSS:

```
[data-box="<h1 class='my-div'> A Simple Heading</h1>"] {
 color: red;
}
```

This should turn the text of your div red. You can add whatever CSS properties when selecting the attribute.